# How to let users change their own profiles?

Tags: 7, users

I have a site running Drupal 7.9 and users can register for their own account. Some of the fields they have to input can change over time (email adress and phone number(s)). Is there any way for me to make it so the user can change his/her own email address and phone numbers?

The only thing I could find in the documentation (and controlpanel) was how to enable users to change their own username, which gets me sort-of there but not quite.

Also, I tried googling this for the longest time but I couldn't find anything. Maybe my search terms were wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

By default, users can change their own profile information, including their email address, and excluding the username. To change the username, the user must have special permissions. To change the profile informations, go to example.com/user in your website, then click the "Edit" button.

Comment: Uhm, yeah this is exactly what I did not need. I did not ask how to enable users to update their own **username** but I asked if it were possible for user X to change his/her own **email address**. Is that possible? Because appearently you cannot change your username (duhh) and your email address, which is strange in my opinion

Comment: @SebastiaanFranken The first line says users can change their user profile information by default.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you CAN give users the permission to change their own usernames. Go to admin/people/permissions and then under "user" > "change own user name." But I realize this was not your original question.

Like Marius said, by default users can change their profile information, including their email address, so I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it maybe?

Comment: Hello John, I have a site running Drupal 7.9 and I want to make it so that normal users can change their own **registration email address**. This seems to be impossible because when I log in as a test user I cannot change the email address. I have configured that users cannot register themselves. Can this be the source of my problems? It **is true** that a user can change their email, but I only want an email field, not all the other stuff like timezone and languages.

Answer (score 0):

if the edit button isn't present at your website, maybe you're using a custom template like me hehe, try to change your site to a default stock template go to the user account and see what is the URL address, or read the users module and figure out how do the users to edit their own data, actually i haven't tried yet, but i'm with the same problem so i'll do it....

but, it's true, users can change their own account data, change username requires the permission that you already know...

I wish us luck jejeje